# Make request to external server from vaadin client and return JSON response to my sever

Tags: vaadin

Working with an api that gives me an access token which works only with client ip, so I`m trying to make a request to that external site on client and return the JSON response to my server. The question is how to make the request and store JSON on client so I could send it to server then.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at Vaadin's

> Integrating JavaScript Components and Extensions

here:

https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/gwt/gwt-javascript.html#gwt.javascript.rpc

You can create a JavaScript connector component that you can then use to make RPC's like so:

```
@JavaScript({"mycomponent-connector.js"})
public class MyComponent extends AbstractJavaScriptComponent {

    public MyComponent(){
        // when you create the component 
        // add a function that can be called from the JavaScript
        addFunction("returnResponse", new JavaScriptFunction() {
            @Override
           public void call(JsonArray arguments) {
               String response = arguments.getString(0));
               // do whatever
            }
        });
    }

    // set up a way to make the request
    public void makeRequest(String url) {
        callFunction("makeRequest", url);
    }

}
```

with the JavaScript file `mycomponent-connector.js` (using `XMLHttpRequest` example):

```
window.com_example_mypackage_MyComponent =
function() {
    var connector = this;

    // add a method to the connector
    this.makeRequest = function(theUrl){
        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
                connector.returnResponse(xmlHttp.responseText);
            }
        };
        xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous 
        xmlHttp.send(null);
   }
};
```

Calling  the method `MyComponent.makeRequest("myurl")` on the server side will fire the `makeRequest` method on the client. When the response is returned we call `connector.returnResponse(xmlHttp.responseText)` to send this back to the server and be handled by `"returnResponse"` function added in the constructor of `MyComponent`.

Comment: I`m might be stupid but I like when people explain so detailed=)
Thank you, appreciate your time.